# Will SparkSQL have better performance than native SQL procedure on MS SQL Server ？

Tags: count, apache-spark-sql, ssas, distinct, mdx

This is a general question. We have a reporting application, which is based on SQL SERVER and SSAS (OLAP). We ran MDX query from Store procedure, there are some distinct count performance issue when use SSAS, Currently we are not having "big" data, it will take 7~8 sec to get the result. But we need plan for the future to avoid the vertically scaling issue of MS SQL SERVER. We don't want to introduce the heavy hadoop system to our applicaiton (maybe in future). So we are considering Spark and SparkSQL. We only need 90 days data for report, so please give your comments on this. Will this sparkSQL solution be faster than MDX query (SSAS/OLAP) on distinct count ? let's say 2 spark nodes in cluster.

- 1.load 90 days data in spark sql

  2. cache the data in spark
  3. query and aggregate
  4. refresh data by night job

Comment: If you only need optimization for a single report have you explored all the alternatives for optimizing the distinct counts? http://sqlblog.com/blogs/mosha/archive/2007/11/22/optimizing-count-filter-expressions-in-mdx.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Spark uses the storage of Hadoopp i.e. HDFS(in most cases) and its own computing technique. So if you want to use Spark you need to have hadoop.
Indeed SparkSQL is much more faster than MS SQL server if the data is quite huge and provided your cluster is having 5-6 nodes. More the number of datanodes, the higher is the computing speed of Spark.

> For example, if your dataset size is around 100-120 GB , Now if you
>   run the query in SQL server it takes 10 mins (suppose) the same when
>   executed in Spark it will take 1 min or less.

So depending upon your business requirement you can choose either Hadoop or Spark or HDFS+Spark.

Answer (score 0):

100-120G is not considered big table in sql server. With proper index you should get usual aggreation result in seconds. Spark has overhead to each query. In usual cases (even with large volumn data) I found it slower than MS sql server